# Compass: Compiling Style Sheets Changes "Black" to "#000"

Tags: css, compass-sass, sass

I am using compass to produce my CSS stylesheets.

In my style sheets, I have several mixins that are used to generate classes. Many of these classes have the word "black" in them.

Everything works fine. However, when I go to compile my scss stylesheets for production, "black" is replaced with #000 in the final style sheet, which breaks my classes.

How can I prevent this?

The code I am using to compile the style sheet is:

```
compass compile -e production --force
```

This is the command listed in the [compass documents](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/production-css/).

Comment: Why is this breaking your classes? Black and #000 are identical in their resulting appearance.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't explain well. This is how my Scss looks `.black { color: black; }`. This is what Compass produces `.#000 {color: #000;}` . The HTML is `<div class="black">`, so the `.#000` black class no longer works.

Comment: having classes with such names calls for trouble... Unless you are really working with colorschemes you should pick names that actually are sematically meaningful.

Comment: Yes I am working with colour schemes (I am making a catalog of colours). I can change the names, but that makes the code less readable. If it wasn't for colour schemes I could use something else such as .alert{} or .primary{} and the code would still be readable. I can understand compass changing `color:black`, but shouldn't it leave `.black` alone.

Comment: @big_smile aah I see. Seems like a bug in compass then. How about calling it .color_black ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the color keywords are being interpreted as color values, not as strings. You can coerce them into strings by surrounding them with quotes. For example:

```
$classname: "black";
$color: black;

.#{$classname} {
  color: #{$color};
}
```

In that way, the color property value will be compressed, but the class name will not.